# sending mass email to new employees with PDF attached

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008-r2

I have handful of employees joining to the company soon. and i have all of their records ( i.e DOB,F_name, L_name, demographics information)in my SQL database. we usually had HR sending welcome packet to them manually. Now we are trying to automate the task, and send it using a HR email ID to x number (send mass email) of people to their respective emails, with an attached PDF with their name. 
Is there a way we could do that using SQL,SSRS or SSIS?

things to be taken in to consideration:

1) it has to be mass email

2) utilize SQL database as a source.

3) update multiple field in PDF for individual person like Name, Email_ID

4) attach PDF to the respective person email and send an email.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **Enterprise Edition** of SQL Server, you can use **Data Driven Subscriptions** to email reports with the Employee as a parameter so each on gets their own information.

You would have a query with the Employees e-mail address to use as the TO: and use their ID as a parameter to pass to the report to filter for that employee's information.

When you run the report, it runs the query to get a separate record for each employee and churns out a separate report.

[MSDN - Data Driven Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150(v=sql.110).aspx%22MSDN%22)